# Hosted ArcGIS Online feature does not return any data?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I would like to share a table as a feature service hosted in ArcGIS Online.  I am able to publish the table as a feature service but when using the REST API interface with for ArcGIS Server I am unable to successfully return data for a simple `1=1` for my where clause. I am receive an error which states `Unable to perform query. Please check your parameters.
No return fields were requested.`

What could be the cause of this?  This data is shared to the public, so a token should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is saying you need to specify some output fields so if you are using the browser to test there should be an Out Fields text input. You can either put in a comma  separated list of attributes names or use * for all. Via the REST API you set this as the outFields parameter.